# Outlook 2007 VBA code to jump to (open) IMAP Inbox

Tags: vba, outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, imap

I am using Outlook to sync mail with GMail via IMAP.

Outlook's default shortcut to go to the Inbox (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) opens the original Inbox, not the new default IMAP Inbox (which I have specified as the new Outlook default e-mail account).

I would like to create VBA code that I can bind to another keystroke, which will open the IMAP Inbox.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters♦ - why are you updating thousands of old posts removing the outlook-vba tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this would be to create a button on the toolbar that searches for your IMAP folder and calls display on it.
Then you can assign a keyboard shortcut to that button and use that.
the other way would be to use winapi to hook the shortcut and call you search and display.

76mel

Answer (score 0):

-right-click DESKTOP
-click NEW > SHORTCUT
-for OUTLOOK 2003 type (including the double-quotes): "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\OUTLOOK.EXE" Outlook://SUBSTITUTE-OUTLOOK-INBOX-NAME-HERE/Inbox

-for OUTLOOK 2007 type (including the double-quotes): "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12\OUTLOOK.EXE" Outlook://SUBSTITUTE-OUTLOOK-INBOX-NAME-HERE/Inbox

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this is still relevant to someone; adding to dakruhm's answer:

It's best to add the `/recycle` switch to the command. That way, if Outlook is open, a new Outlook window will NOT be created. (Use that unless you WANT one to be created.)

The command (for Outlook 2007) therefore looks as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle Outlook://Gmail IMAP/Inbox
```

Also, dakruhm's answer was very detailed, but he forgot to mention that you need to assign a shortcut key. I've checked this, and if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, there seems to be a delay until the command is carried out. I therefore use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, which takes some getting used to, but works much quicker.